# When I sign a git commit, what is my signature actually based on?

Tags: digital-signature, git

I'm curious about what data actually gets signed when I sign a git commit or tag? Is it simply the commit message and metadata?

How could I manually duplicate the signature, use gpg instead of git?

Comment: This post goes into these details: https://people.kernel.org/monsieuricon/what-does-a-pgp-signature-on-a-git-commit-prove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the function "commit_tree_extended" in the git source code for the file "commit.c" (e.g., in this [blob](https://github.com/git/git/blob/72c4083ddf91b489b7b7b812df67ee8842177d98/commit.c#L1462-L1527)).

Based on reviewing this function, when you sign a commit it seems to be signing a string that contains identifiers for the tree object_id, parent object_id, author, committer, encoding (if not utf-8), commit_extra_header, and the commit message.

Comment: Excellent, so commit message and metadata was on the right track. Thank you for the precision. :-)

Comment: The joys of open source :)